# Why does System Settings in 18.10 using Unity show 18.04?

Tags: unity, 18.10, system-settings, unity-control-center

After upgrading to 18.10 I noticed that the details in my System Settings still said 18.04. After noticing that I checked with lsb_release -a
The output looks like this:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic
```

I also checked and apt seems to update from cosmic, so this seems to only be a visual bug.

I'm using the Unity Desktop, if this changes anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone reading this and having a similar problem, I just managed to fix this, by simply purging the unity-control-center. This will change the default one to the gnome-control-center.

Since the reasons I still use unity weren't really connected to the control center this was imo the most future-proof solution.

So a simple

```
sudo apt purge unity-control-center
```

fixed my problem

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using the Unity Desktop, if this changes anything.

The [`unity-control-center`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/unity-control-center) package hasn't been updated for 18.10. It's version is still `15.04.0+18.04.20180216-0ubuntu1` ... and `/usr/share/unity-control-center/ui/UbuntuLogo.png` is still showing 18.04. That's the image you see there.

Comment: Will this be updated? Or am I basically out of luck if I want the 18.10 logo while still using unity?

Comment: @Barbarian772 As you can probably guess, Canonical have stopped maintaining Unity and related packages. You can file a bug report, but whether anyone will fix it... I suppose this was an oversight, since the default GNOME Control Center uses text to show the version information (so images didn't need to be periodically updated for it).

Comment: Ok, managed to change to the gnome-control-center, by purging the ubuntu one. Thanks for the hint :)